# php echo database row results into a card

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I am trying to echo my database results into a bootstrap 4 card, each row result will be in its own bootstrap card.

I have been able to show the results in a table

**Echo to table - THIS WORKS**

```
<table class="table table-striped">

  <?php echo "<table class='table table-striped mb-none'>";

// table header
echo "<tr><th>Company Name</th><th>Date Requested</th><th>Request By</th><th>Graphic Type</th><th>Double Sided</th><th>Design Info</th><th>Purpose</th><th>Approved</th><th>Approval Date</th></tr>";

// output data of each row
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($designresult)) {

    echo "<tr><td>".$row["companyName"]."</td><td>".$row["dateReq"]."</td><td>".$row["yourName"]."</td><td>".$row["graphicType"]."</td><td>".$row["doubleS"]."</td><td>".$row["info"]."</td><td>".$row["purpose"]."</td><td>".$row["approved"]."</td><td>".$row["appDate"]."</td></tr>";
}

// table footer

echo "</table>";

?>
```

**My attempt at echoing into cards**

```
<?php 
// output data of each row
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($designresult)) {

echo "
<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow"> div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Track Design</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p> Company Name ".$row["companyName"]."; </p>
          </div>
        </div>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Problem, do you have it?

Comment: Yeah, the php script just loads error, when I add the card php attempt, meaning there is a code error to start with in the card echo

Answer (score 0):

In the first solution you are escaping `"` in using `'` quotes.

In the second one, you are using `"` in your HTML code. As you echo that and your echo starts with `"` aswell, you are ending the echo.

```
echo "<div class=" <-- Ending the echo, not starting the class name
```

You have to change it to this:

```
echo "<div class='card mb-4 box-shadow'>"
```

You can also close the PHP tag:

```
<?php 
// output data of each row
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($designresult)) {

?>

<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow"> 
    <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Track Design</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p> Company Name <?php echo $row["companyName"]; ?> </p>
    </div>
</div>

<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe just closing php tag `?>` is __simpler__?

Comment: @u_mulder Yeah, another good solution. Let me add this ..

Comment: I have fixed the error above, however the page is 500 error, meaning their is a error in the code

Comment: @fantasiaa123 Which error do you get?

Comment: fixed and thanks both, your guidance has worked